# Layers Control and null as first argument

Tags: angular

I am using Leaflet library and I want to add just overlay layer on the map and the first argument sholud be `null`, right?

But when I do this:

```
var layerControl = L.control.layers(null,overlay).addTo(this.mapa);
```

I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LayersObject | undefined'.
```

I am working in Angular 7 and it is .ts file.

Can I get some advice, please?

Comment: Hi Marko, try using `undefined` instead of `null`.

Comment: Thank you a lot @CodeWarrior. This was probbably easy for you but I am just junior :)

Comment: All good mate, we were all junior once. I have posted the same as an answer, could you please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `undefined` instead of `null` in the first argument.